# Как заставить Termux работать на Android 6?

Tags: android, termux

Ну, собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Подогнали старый телефон, с шестеркой на борту, и захотел я использовать его для всякого хакерокодерского. Вспомнил про термукс (давно не пользовался, аж слеза от ностальгии пролилась). Оказалось, что он с 20-го перестал работать с дроидами ниже 6-го. Ну, скачал старую версию, попробовал обновить систему, нифига. Репозитория не существует и хоть тресни. Как мне хотя-бы нано поставить, а там поковырять репозитории, и вообще, где находится sources.list у термушки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Старые репозитории, которые хранились на bintray, перестали работать. Теперь появился https://packages.termux.dev/ . Там находится deb-строка для репо разных типов и версий. Чтобы заменить репо там, нам надо nano поставить. Пакеты можно взять из https://packages.termux.dev/apt . Находишь нано (там удобная система сортировки, поймёшь), нажимаешь на поделиться, выбираешь термукс. Заходишь в термукс, с помощью apt ставишь скачанный нано (пишешь `apt install ./имя_пакета.deb`, зависимости докачиваешь подобным образом). Далее пишешь `cd $PREFIX` (там, кстати, и находится наша Linux-подсистема, иначе говоря, префикс), потом оттуда переходишь в /etc/apt, прописываешь `nano sources.list`. Потом вставляешь в конец файла deb-строку с новым репо, подходящим тебе. Потом уже можно смело прописывать apt update apt upgrade. Всё! Для теста поставь питон или вим. Хотя, метасплоит тоже можно. Но учти! Пакеты больше не будут обновляться! То есть, в идеале смарт прошить. Сам пользуюсь рутанутым Pixel Experience.

Comment: Сейчас уже появилась поддержка android  5 и 6, подробности в Вики на гитхабе проекта
https://github.com/termux/termux-app/wiki/Termux-on-android-5-or-6

Answer (score 0):

Никак. `Termux` работает только на `Android 7` и выше. Старые версии работают на `Android 5` и выше, но они не обновляют репозитории.